# How can I log a the value of a property in Wix?

Tags: wix

I want to know if in the same directory of my setup (CURRENTDIR) there is a file named "pippo.txt". So I made the following property.

```
<Property Id="TROVAPIPPO">
      <DirectorySearch Id="trovadir" Depth="0" Path="CURRENTDIR">
        <FileSearch Id="trovafile" Name="pippo.txt" />
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>
```

Now I want to display the value of this property in the log file (in temp folder). But I don't know how.

Comment: You can create custom action that stores this property on .txt , also your property values are by default stored in the msi log file(if you run installing the msi with verbous log on)

Answer (score 3):

Run your installer from the command line with `msiexec /i yourInstaller.msi /L*v yourLogFile.txt`

Changes to MSI properties will be logged.  The log files are pretty big, but it'll be in there somewhere.